# In a for loop, how to manipulate dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am a R beginner; I am now moving form SAS to R.

I have so many data frames in R called x1,x2,x3... xn, and they all have columns called a and b. So I try to add a column called c, in which c was added by a and b. Also I want to add this c column to all the data frames with for loop. How could I do this? This is an sample code, but it does't work.

```
a<-c(1:3)
b<-c(2:4)
x1<-data.frame(a,b)
a<-c(11:13)
b<-c(22:24)
x2<-data.frame(a,b)
for (i in 1:2)
{paste0("x",i)$c<-a+b}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches you might take. I have assumed that you need to keep each data frame isolated. Here are two possibilities depending on your required outcome.

#### List of data frames

```
library(dplyr)

x <- list(x1 = x1, x2 = x2)

lapply(x, mutate, c = a + b)

# $x1
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 2 3 5
# 3 3 4 7
# 
# $x2
#    a  b  c
# 1 11 22 33
# 2 12 23 35
# 3 13 24 37
```

#### Bind rows and add id column

```
df <- bind_rows(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, .id = "source")

df %>% mutate(c = a + b)

#   source  a  b  c
# 1     x1  1  2  3
# 2     x1  2  3  5
# 3     x1  3  4  7
# 4     x2 11 22 33
# 5     x2 12 23 35
# 6     x2 13 24 37
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But if there are so many dataframes x1,x2,x3... xn and that is to say, n is so big. It is not convenient to write code.

Comment: @hongxingli, then you take up a vector of names and apply the same logic

Answer (score 0):

You could first **put the data frame names in a vector**

```
> paste0("x",1:2) -> names.df
> names.df
[1] "x1" "x2"
```

Use the vector of names to **put the data frames in a list**

```
> Lst.df<-lapply(  names.df,function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
> Lst.df
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4

[[2]]
   a  b
1 11 22
2 12 23
3 13 24
```

Then apply **`lapply` over the list of data frames**

```
> lapply(Lst.df,function(x) {x$c <- x$a +x$b;x})
[[1]]
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 2 3 5
3 3 4 7

[[2]]
   a  b  c
1 11 22 33
2 12 23 35
3 13 24 37
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it is the best way to my problem. Thank again!